# How to combine stat_ecdf with geom_ribbon?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to draw an ECDF of some data with a "confidence interval" represented via a shaded region using **ggplot2**. I am having trouble combining `geom_ribbon()` with `stat_ecdf()` to achieve the effect I am after.

Consider the following example data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(variable = rlnorm(100) + 2)
dat <- transform(dat, lower = variable - 2, upper = variable + 2)

> head(dat)
  variable     lower    upper
1 2.534484 0.5344838 4.534484
2 3.201587 1.2015872 5.201587
3 2.433602 0.4336018 4.433602
4 6.929713 4.9297132 8.929713
5 3.390284 1.3902836 5.390284
6 2.440225 0.4402254 4.440225
```

I am able to produce an ECDF of `variable` using

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable)) +
    geom_step(stat = "ecdf")
```

However I am unable to use `lower` and `upper` as the `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics of `geom_ribbon()` to superimpose the confidence interval on the plot as another layer. I have tried:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), stat = "ecdf") +
    geom_step(stat = "ecdf")
```

but this raises the following error

```
Error: geom_ribbon requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin, ymax
```

Is there a way to coax `geom_ribbon()` into working with `stat_ecdf()` to produce a shaded confidence interval? Or, can anyone suggest an alternative means of adding a shaded polygon defined by `lower` and `upper` as a layer to the ECDF plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (a bit of shot in the dark):

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = variable,ymin = ..y..-2,ymax = ..y..+2), stat = "ecdf",alpha=0.2) +
  geom_step(stat = "ecdf")
```

Ok, so that's not the same thing as what you trying to do, but it should explain what's going on. The `stat` is returning a data frame with just the original x and the computed y, so I think that's all you have to work with. i.e. `stat_ecdf` only computes the cumulative distribution function for a single x at a time.

The only other thing I can think of is the obvious, calculating the lower and upper separately, something like this:

```
l <- ecdf(dat$lower)
u <- ecdf(dat$upper)
v <- ecdf(dat$variable)
dat$lower1 <- l(dat$variable)
dat$upper1 <- u(dat$variable)
dat$variable1 <- v(dat$variable)

ggplot(dat,aes(x = variable)) + 
  geom_step(aes(y = variable1)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = upper1,ymax = lower1),alpha = 0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. Could you expand on your last sentence? Not sure I follow this fully, but as far as I can tell from your answer, I can't do this via `stat_ecdf` if `lower` and `upper` already exist? The +/- 2 bit was just dummy data; the CI info I have is the result of posterior simulation of a derived statistic computed from a fitted model.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes, I think it's not possible directly in ggplot (although that would be a nice feature to add, I think). All I meant with the last bit was that you might have to calculate all the ECDF values manually and then plot them.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, compute the cumulative proportion directly. I'll give that a do. +1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly how you want to reflect the CI, but `ggplot_build()` lets you get the generated data back from the plot, you can then overplot what you like.

This chart shows:

- red = original ribbon
- blue = takes the original CI vectors and applies to the ecdf curve
- green = calculates the ecdf of upper and lower series and plots

[image]

```
    g<-ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable)) +
      geom_step(stat = "ecdf") +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha=0.5, fill="red") 

    inside<-ggplot_build(g)
    matched<-merge(inside$data[[1]],data.frame(x=dat$variable,dat$lower,dat$upper),by=("x"))

    g + 
      geom_ribbon(data=matched, aes(x = x, 
                                      ymin = y + dat.upper-x,
                                      ymax = y - x + dat.lower), 
                    alpha=0.5, fill="blue") +
      geom_ribbon(data=matched, aes(x = x, 
                                      ymin = ecdf(dat.lower)(x),
                                      ymax = ecdf(dat.upper)(x)), 
                    alpha=0.5, fill="green")
```

Comment: Thanks Troy; your final idea, once I realised what the plot showed, is similar to @joran's idea, namely that one could compute the  appropriate `y` data for the lower and upper CIs using `ecdf()`. The green ribbon is essentially what I want to depict.